# Running Dell Boomi atom on Docker

Tags: docker, boomi

I retrieved the most recent image using `docker pull boomi/atom:2.3.0`

I then run the following script (using placeholders for USERNAME, PASSWORD and ACCOUNT_ID):

```
#!/bin/bash
atom_name=boomidemo01
docker stop $atom_name
docker rm $atom_name
docker run -p 9090:9090 -h boomidemo01 -e URL="platform.boomi.com" \
-e BOOMI_USERNAME=<USERNAME> -e BOOMI_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> \
-e BOOMI_ATOMNAME=$atom_name \
-e BOOMI_CONTAINERNAME=$atom_name \
-e BOOMI_ACCOUNTID=<ACCOUNT_ID>  \
--name $atom_name \
-d -t boomi/atom:2.3.0
```

But the atom fails to start (not able to connect on port 9090 via a browser on http://127.0.0.1:9090). Did anyone managed to use docker for running a Boomi atom?

Comment: What do the logs say? Remove `-d` from the `docker run` command so you can tail the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured it out... the following script works

```
#!/bin/bash
atom_name=boomidemo01
host_dir=/home/user/Boomi
docker stop $atom_name
docker rm $atom_name

docker run -p 9090:9090 -h $atom_name \
    -v $host_dir:/home/boomi/host_dir \
    -e URL=https://platform.boomi.com \
    -e BOOMI_USERNAME=<USERNAME> \
    -e BOOMI_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> \
    -e BOOMI_ATOMNAME=$atom_name \
    -e BOOMI_CONTAINERNAME=$atom_name \
    -e BOOMI_ACCOUNTID=<ACCOUNT_ID> \
    -e PROXY_HOST= \
    -e PROXY_USERNAME= \
    -e PROXY_PASSWORD= \
    -e PROXY_PORT= \
    -e DOCKERUID= \
    -e SYMLINKS_DIR= \
    -e ATOM_LOCALHOSTID=$atom_name \
    -e INSTALL_TOKEN= \
    --name $atom_name \
    -d -t boomi/atom:2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the docker install script from within the UI.
2. Generate the token.
3. Run the script with the name, and token.

The port does not matter because Atomsphere is never pinged. It fetches processes for you.